# I can't import pypotarce or potrace

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, installation

can't install pypotarce

this is error msg

```
path>pip install pypotrace   
Collecting pypotrace
  Using cached pypotrace-0.3.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pypotrace) (1.25.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: pypotrace
  Building wheel for pypotrace (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pypotrace (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      A setup.py file already exists. Using it.
      Package libagg was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libagg.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libagg' found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gks9b_vy\pypotrace_b6652817fe024dc8b5c073d482539a54\setup.py", line 28, in <module>
          build(setup_kwargs)
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gks9b_vy\pypotrace_b6652817fe024dc8b5c073d482539a54\build.py", line 19, in build
          extra_compile_args = pkg_config("libagg", '--cflags')
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gks9b_vy\pypotrace_b6652817fe024dc8b5c073d482539a54\build.py", line 11, in pkg_config
          return subprocess.check_output(["pkg-config", command, pkg_name]).decode(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--cflags', 'libagg']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-plos75tj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\api.py", line 58, in build_wheel
          return WheelBuilder.make_in(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-plos75tj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 88, in make_in
          wb.build(target_dir=directory)
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-plos75tj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 121, in build
          self._build(zip_file)
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-plos75tj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 182, in _build
          self._run_build_command(setup)
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-plos75tj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\poetry\core\masonry\builders\wheel.py", line 248, in _run_build_command
          subprocess.check_call([
        File "C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Users/A/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gks9b_vy\\pypotrace_b6652817fe024dc8b5c073d482539a54\\setup.py', 'build', '-b', 'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gks9b_vy\\pypotrace_b6652817fe024dc8b5c073d482539a54\\build', '--build-purelib', 'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gks9b_vy\\pypotrace_b6652817fe024dc8b5c073d482539a54\\build\\lib', '--build-platlib', 'C:\\Users\\A\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gks9b_vy\\pypotrace_b6652817fe024dc8b5c073d482539a54\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pypotrace
Failed to build pypotrace
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pypotrace, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm making drawing function by processed svg files and its created with pygcode.

And I tried install and use pypotrace. But I failed to import and use pypotrace.

I tried install pypotrace-0.1.2 and agg-2.6-master(libagg.m4, libagg.pc.in)

And two libagg files move to pypotrace directory and I tried install pypotrace by ''pip install pypotrace'' function but I failed.

This is chatGPT's solution but it doesn't works for me.

And 'potrace' can't import too.

Any other way to solve this problem?

python version 3.11.4
cmake version 3.27.7

I'm sorry to my poor english

```
# test import pypotrace code
# its not perfect code 

import numpy as np
# import potrace
import pypotrace
from PIL import Image



image = Image.open("static/complete_png/20240126-160034.png").convert("L") 
bitmap = np.array(image) > 128 

potrace_bitmap = potrace.Bitmap(bitmap)

potrace_struct = potrace_bitmap.trace()

with open("selfie.svg", "w") as f:
    width, height = image.size  
    f.write(f'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="{width}" height="{height}">\n')
    for curve in potrace_struct:
        f.write('<path d="')
        start_point = curve.start_point
        f.write(f'M {start_point.x},{start_point.y} ')
        for segment in curve:
            if segment.is_corner:
                
                f.write(f'L {segment.c.x},{segment.c.y} ')
            else:
                c1, c2 = segment.c1, segment.c2
                f.write(f'C {c1.x},{c1.y} {c2.x},{c2.y} {segment.end_point.x},{segment.end_point.y} ')
        f.write('" fill="none" stroke="black"/>\n')
    f.write('</svg>')
```

Comment: Your error contains this line `No package 'libagg' found`. Did you follow the [pypotrace install instructions](https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/)? It seems a bit trickier to install it on Windows. Instructions for Linux-based systems are far more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Windows machine. This is the installation procedure for windows given by  klonuo on PyPi:

Use MinGW system. So assuming user has MinGW available, additional two packages are needed:

1. potrace source: http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading
2. agg source: http://www.antigrain.com/download/index.html

I extracted both packages in my `C:\src` folder. Both are easy to build by executing `./configure;` make and `./autogen.sh; make` respectively, on MSYS prompt.

After that, we need some variables to build pypotrace successfully:

First, includes paths:

- “numpy/arrayobject.h”: C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include
- potrace headers: C:/src/potrace-1.11/src
- agg headers: C:/src/agg-2.5

there is a little catch for agg includes, as paths referenced in cpp sources point to `agg2/*.h` while in downloaded agg package we don’t have `agg2` folder. For me it was easiest to rename `C:/src/agg-2.5/include` to `C:/src/agg-2.5/agg2` and use `C:/src/agg-2.5` as agg include folder.

Next, libdirs for libraries we build above:

- potrace: `C:/src/potrace-1.11/src/.libs`
- `agg: C:/src/agg-2.5/src`

and we can make pypotrace build command, and execute it:

```
python setup.py build_ext -IC:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include;C:/src/potrace-1.11/src;C:/src/agg-2.5 -LC:/src/potrace-1.11/src/.libs;C:/src/agg-2.5/src
```

Finally install the package:

```
C:\src\git\pypotrace>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
copying potrace\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\potrace
copying potrace\agg\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\potrace\agg
running build_ext
skipping 'potrace\_potrace.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'potrace\bezier.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'potrace/agg\curves.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
running install_lib
creating C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace
creating C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace\agg
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\potrace\agg\curves.pyd -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace\agg
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\potrace\agg\__init__.py -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace\agg
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\potrace\bezier.pyd -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\potrace\_potrace.pyd -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace
copying build\lib.win32-2.7\potrace\__init__.py -> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace
byte-compiling C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace\agg\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\potrace\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pypotrace-0.1-py2.7.egg-info
Running tests
```

See [https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/#:~:text=numpy%0A%24%20pip%20install%20.-,Windows,-Thanks%20to%20klonuo](https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/#:%7E:text=numpy%0A%24%20pip%20install%20.-,Windows,-Thanks%20to%20klonuo)